# Solution to the cracker barrel peg game / triangle game

Tags: python, game

I wrote a small script that finds the solution to the cracker barrel peg game / triangle game.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/abaldwin99/170bdde88bee434657aa)

```
"""A small script that finds the solution to
the cracker barrel peg game / triangle game.

Instructions along with one of the game's solution can be found here:
http://www.joenord.com/puzzles/peggame/

It finds the solution by repeatedly playing games and making random
decisions until a game leaves one peg. The slot's are numbered
0 - 14 in sequential order (Top to Bottom, Left to Right)

    /0\
   /1 2\
  /3 4 5\
  etc etc

Another objective of this game is to leave the board with
8 pegs and no possible jumps. To find that solution change the
final if statement as follows:

if triangle.total_peg() == 8:

Language python 2.7
"""

import random


class Slot:
    """
    Represents a single slot opening of the triangle game.
    This class holds the slot number, it's possible jump
    dictionary and helper functions around maintaining slots.
    """

    def __init__(self, num, jump_dict):
        self.num = num
        self.jump_dict = jump_dict
        self.peg = True

    def has_peg(self):
        return self.peg

    def add_peg(self):
        self.peg = True

    def remove_peg(self):
        self.peg = False

    def possible_jump(self, board):
        """ Determine possible jumps for a given peg

        :param board: The board to check possible jumps against
        :return: Dictionary of possible jumps
        """
        assert self.has_peg()
        possible_jump_dict = {}
        for jump_over in self.jump_dict:
            jump_to = self.jump_dict[jump_over]
            if board[jump_over].has_peg() and not board[jump_to].has_peg():
                possible_jump_dict[jump_over] = jump_to
        return possible_jump_dict


class Triangle:
    """
    Represents a single board of the triangle game
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes the board for a new game.
        The board consists of slot 15 objects
        """
        self.board = [Slot(0, {1: 3, 2: 5}),
                      Slot(1, {3: 6, 4: 8}),
                      Slot(2, {4: 7, 5: 9}),
                      Slot(3, {4: 5, 1: 0, 6: 10, 7: 12}),
                      Slot(4, {7: 11, 8: 13}),
                      Slot(5, {2: 0, 4: 3, 8: 12, 9: 14}),
                      Slot(6, {3: 1, 7: 8}),
                      Slot(7, {4: 2, 8: 9}),
                      Slot(8, {4: 1, 7: 6, }),
                      Slot(9, {5: 2, 8: 7}),
                      Slot(10, {6: 3, 11: 12}),
                      Slot(11, {7: 4, 12: 13}),
                      Slot(12, {11: 10, 7: 3, 8: 5, 13: 14}),
                      Slot(13, {12: 11, 8: 4}),
                      Slot(14, {13: 12, 9: 5})]

        self.jump_history = []

    def jump(self, jump_from, jump_over, jump_to):
        """Executes a jump action

        :param jump_from: Peg number to jump from
        :param jump_over: Peg number to be jumped over and removed
        :param jump_to: Empty slot number for the peg to jump into
        """
        self.board[jump_from].remove_peg()
        self.board[jump_over].remove_peg()
        self.board[jump_to].add_peg()
        self.jump_history.append([jump_from, jump_over, jump_to])

    def total_peg(self):
        return sum(slot.has_peg() for slot in self.board)

    def random_jump(self):
        """ Selects a random slot that contains a peg and then randomly
        selects one of it's possible jumps.

        :return: Tuple containing a single slot and it's jump coordinates
        """
        slot_choice = [i for i in range(15)]
        random.shuffle(slot_choice)
        for slot in slot_choice:
            if self.board[slot].has_peg():
                possible_jump = self.board[slot].possible_jump(self.board)
                if possible_jump:
                    jump_over = random.choice(possible_jump.keys())
                    jump_to = possible_jump[jump_over]
                    return slot, jump_over, jump_to
        return None

    def remove_first_peg(self):
        """
        The first action of every game is to remove a peg from a full board
        This function randomly removes one peg from a full board
        """
        first_peg = random.choice(self.board)
        first_peg.remove_peg()
        self.jump_history.append([first_peg.num])

    def play_one_game(self):
        self.remove_first_peg()
        while True:
            next_jump = self.random_jump()
            if next_jump:
                self.jump(*next_jump)
            else:
                break


def main():

    total_games = 0

    # Keep playing games until a single peg is left on the board
    while True:
        total_games += 1
        triangle = Triangle()
        triangle.play_one_game()
        if triangle.total_peg() == 1:
            break

    print '***Game #' + str(total_games) + ' Report***'
    for slot in triangle.board:
        print str(slot.num) + ' ' + str(slot.has_peg())
    print 'Jump History:'
    print triangle.jump_history
    print 'Total Pegs Remaining: ' + str(triangle.total_peg())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm looking for any critiques, from style to class structure to variable names.

Comment: Excellent first question, you provided the link and the code is well documented, you are welcome at CodeReview!

Comment: Thanks.  I really worked on trying to make this as presentable possible.

Comment: I used Prolog to solve this. I agree with otherwise published win counts (1=29,760, 2=14,880, 4=85,258, 5=1,550), but I've seen various losing oath counts much higher than mine. I'm thinking they counted jumps in losing oaths, not the path up to point of dead end. I get: 1=2,193,179 and 5=323,893.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your documentation (good work on including it, by the way) mentions that this is Python 2.7. In that case, your classes should be *"new-style"* and inherit from `object` (see e.g. [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54867/3001761))

While I mention the documentation, it would be nice to cover the *format* of `jump_dict`, e.g.:

```
"""
...
:param jump_dict: The possible jumps from the slot, in
    the form {jump_over: jump_to}.
... 
"""
```

---

Having the board laid out within `Board.__init__` seems a little inflexible; have a go at making the number of rows an instantiation argument, defaulting to the current `5`, and see if you can write some code to calculate what slots must be provided (and linked to which others) for a given size.

I think the structure might end up being a bit neater if you switch the dictionaries, too - if each `Slot` stored the slots it can be jumped to *from* the logic gets simpler. Really, it's the *empty* slots that are key here, not the full ones!

---

There is duplication of information here:

```
def jump(self, jump_from, jump_over, jump_to):
```

you define three parameters, when any two would be sufficient to determine the third (e.g. if you know where you're jumping `_from` and `_to`, you can work out where you're jumping `_over`).

---

Finally, the `random` method of solving the puzzle isn't ideal. At the very least I would try to decouple the random solver from the other methods, making it easier to slot in something a bit smarter when you can. For example, imagine:

```
def play_one_game(self, method='random'):
```

What would need to change to make this run while providing for alternative values of `method` later?

Comment: Lot of good stuff to chew on here.  All good points.  The coupling point is really good.  However.... Do you think it's fair to say that the random solution is less complex to program than a recursive solution?   As far as i see it the recursive function executes faster but takes longer to program.

Answer (score 3):

> Another objective of this game is to leave the board with
>   8 pegs and no possible jumps. To find that solution change the
>   final if statement as follows:
>
> `if triangle.total_peg() == 8:`

Wait, I, the user must change the code? Well I can totally do that but it does not fell professional, I suggest:

> Another objective of this game is to leave the board with
>   8 pegs and no possible jumps. To find that solution change the
>   following constant to True:
>
> ```
> EIGHT_PEGS_SOLUTION = False
> ```

and then:

```
while True:
    total_games += 1
    triangle = Triangle()
    triangle.play_one_game()
    pegs_wanted = 8 if EIGHT_PEGS_SOLUTION else 1 
    if triangle.total_peg() == pegs_wanted:
        break
```

Now the user has the only task of swapping a boolean value and there is a much better professional feeling.

Comment: Yea that's fair.  A constant at the top is alot more user friendly.  I think I'm a actually just going to ax that note all together....  I want to keep the script focused on accomplishing one goal

Comment: Even better might be to allow the user to pass in a command line argument for the desired number of pegs remaining. This would make the script flexible to whatever peg number goal the user might have.

Answer (score 1):

I took your code and changed it up a little bit since I wanted the ability to pick which peg to remove first and to see what the moves where. Now you can study the moves and impress your friends. It's not the best code I've ever written but it works as far as I can tell and now you can try to improve on it if you want.

```
"""Original code written by abaldwin99"""
import re
import random
import sys
class Slot:
    def __init__(self, num, jump_d, i): #i is the index in the 2d array used for printing
        self.num = num
        self.nnum = num
        self.i = i
        self.jd = jump_d
        self.peg = True
        self.fpeg = True #final peg movement used for printing

    def has_peg(self):
        return self.peg

    def add_peg(self):
        self.peg = True

    def remove_peg(self):
        self.peg = False

    def possible_jump(self, board):
        assert self.has_peg()
        pjd = {}
        for jump_over in self.jd: #loop through all possible jumps
            jump_to = self.jd[jump_over]    #get the pegs that you can jump too
            if board[jump_over].has_peg() and not board[jump_to].has_peg(): #if current slot has peg and spot to jump to is empty
                pjd[jump_over] = jump_to #add new slot to pjd
        return pjd

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, first_slot):
        self.slot = first_slot
        self.board = [Slot(0, {1: 3, 2: 5}, 0),
                      Slot(1, {3: 6, 4: 8}, 1),
                      Slot(2, {5: 9, 4: 7}, 1),
                      Slot(3, {1: 0, 4:5, 7: 12, 6: 10}, 2),
                      Slot(4, {7:11, 8:13}, 2),
                      Slot(5, {2: 0, 4: 3, 8: 12, 9: 14}, 2),
                      Slot(6, {3: 1, 7: 8}, 3),
                      Slot(7, {4: 2, 8: 9}, 3),
                      Slot(8, {4: 1, 7: 6}, 3),
                      Slot(9, {5: 2, 8: 7}, 3),
                      Slot(10, {6: 3, 11: 12}, 4),
                      Slot(11, {7: 4, 12: 13}, 4),
                      Slot(12, {11: 10, 7: 3, 8: 5, 13: 14}, 4),
                      Slot(13, {12: 11, 8: 4}, 4),
                      Slot(14, {13: 12, 9: 5}, 4)]
        self.history = []
    def jump(self, jump_from, jump_over, jump_to):
        self.board[jump_from].remove_peg()
        self.board[jump_over].remove_peg()
        self.board[jump_to].add_peg()
        self.history.append([jump_from, jump_over, jump_to])

    def total_peg(self):
        return sum(slot.has_peg() for slot in self.board)

    def random_jump(self):
        slot_choice = [i for i in range(15)]    #array of all slots
        random.shuffle(slot_choice) #shuffle slots
        for slot in slot_choice:    #loop through slots
            if self.board[slot].has_peg():  
                possible_jump = self.board[slot].possible_jump(self.board)  #get list of possible jumps
                if possible_jump:
                    jump_over = random.choice(possible_jump.keys())
                    jump_to = possible_jump[jump_over]
                    return slot, jump_over, jump_to
        return None

    def remove_first_peg(self):

        mat = re.match(r'[A-Ea-e]', self.slot)
        if mat: first_peg = self.board[ord(self.slot.upper())-55]
        else: first_peg = self.board[int(self.slot)]
        first_peg.remove_peg()
        self.history.append([first_peg.num])

    def play_one_game(self):
        self.remove_first_peg()
        while True:
            next_jump = self.random_jump()
            if next_jump:
                self.jump(*next_jump)
            else:
                break

    def print_moves(self):
        tri = [[0],[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14]]
        for move in self.history:
            self.print_move(move)
            if len(move) != 1:
                jump_over = self.board[move[1]]
                jump_to = self.board[move[2]]
                jump_over.fpeg, jump_to.fpeg = False, True
                jump_to.nnum = jump_from.nnum

            jump_from = self.board[move[0]]
            jump_from.fpeg = False

            for i in range(len(tri)):
                string = ('/ ')
                for j in range(len(tri[i])):
                    slot = self.board[tri[i][j]]
                    if slot.num == jump_from.num:
                        s = '*'
                    elif len(move) != 1 and slot.num == jump_over.num:
                        index_from = tri[jump_from.i].index(jump_from.num)
                        index_to = tri[jump_to.i].index(jump_to.num)
                        half = len(tri[i])/2.0

                        if tri[i] == tri[jump_from.i]:
                            s = u'\u2190' if (jump_from.num > jump_to.num) else u'\u2192' #-
                        elif (index_from > half or index_to > half ):
                            s = u'\u2196' if (jump_from.num > jump_to.num) else u'\u2198' #\
                        elif ((index_to == half and index_from < half) or (index_from == half and index_to < half)):
                            s = u'\u2196' if (jump_from.num > jump_to.num) else u'\u2198' #\
                        elif ((index_to == half and index_from > half) or (index_from == half and index_to > half)):
                            s = u'\u2197' if (jump_from.num > jump_to.num) else u'\u2199'  #/
                        else:
                            s = u'\u2197' if (jump_from.num > jump_to.num) else u'\u2199'  #/
                    else:
                        if slot.fpeg == True:
                            s = str(slot.nnum)
                            if int(s) > 9:
                                s = chr(int(s)+55)
                        else:
                            s = '.'
                    string += (s + ' ')
                string += '\\'
                print string.center(20, ' ')
            print('')

def main():

    total_games = 0
    print('Slots: /0\ ')
    print('      /1 2\ ')
    print('     /3 4 5\ ')
    print('    /6 7 8 9\ ')
    print('   /A B C D E\ ')
    slot = '-1'
    slots = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E']
    while slot not in slots:
        slot = raw_input('Specify which peg to remove: ').upper()

    while True:

        total_games += 1
        triangle = Triangle(slot)
        triangle.play_one_game()
        if triangle.total_peg() == 1:
            break

    print '***Game #' + str(total_games) + ' Report***'
    for slot in triangle.board:
        print str(slot.num) + ' ' + str(slot.has_peg())
    print 'Jump History:'
    print triangle.history
    print 'Total Pegs Remaining: ' + str(triangle.total_peg())
    triangle.print_moves()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

printing the moves took me a while to figure out and looks the worst by far, but here it is if you want to mess around with it.

Comment: Hey awesome - Being able to see the board in the command line output is great.  It's actually a pretty interesting problem in it's self.  I agree the `print_moves` could use some work to increase readability.  Breaking up the monolithic logic into a series of smaller functions would go a long way.

Comment: @abaldwin99 I tried to make the `print_moves` a little more readable by adding handles. I think it helped quite a bit for readability but I still feel like there is a more logical way of determining which character to use. i.e. `/ \ -`

Comment: @abaldwin99 I just edited it a little bit so now it shows the moves as the current state of the board and the move rather than just the move

Comment: also added unicode characters to show direction of move. The diagonal arrows look pretty bad on my screen unless you increase the font to like size 20